# How can I test database queries without creating mocks

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sequelize.js

I am using ORM like Sequelize to interact with the database but I want to test the queries as unit test how can I do that without creating any fake models or instant methods like using sequelize mock.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mock then don't do it!

Use unit tests to test your database with the real queries - you will most likely need some "setup" and "teardown" scripts/help methods.

If you are new to unit testing, start here: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html